# Java JIT loop unrolling policy?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction, jit, loop-unrolling

What is the loop unrolling policy for JIT? Or if there is no simple answer to that, then is there some way i can check where/when loop unrolling is being performed in a loop?

```
GNode child = null;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
   child = octree.getNeighbor(nn, i, MethodFlag.NONE);
   if(child==null)
      break;
   RecurseForce(leaf, child, dsq, epssq);
}
```

Basically, i have a piece of code above that has a static number of iterations (eight), and it does bad when i leave the for loop as it is. But when i manually unroll the loop, it does significantly better. I am interested in finding out if the JIT actually does unroll the loop, and if not, then why.

Comment: That's a *very, very* specific question that you'll need to analyze for a *specific version* of a *specific JVM* on a *specific platform*. And I guess they "why" can only ever be answered by in-depth analysis of the JIT code.

Comment: You left out one crucial detail: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: @aioobe Its Java Hotspot 64 bit, 1.6.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If* the JVM unrolls the loop is probably best answered by actually [printing the generated assembly](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly). Note that this requires your code to actually be executed as a hot spot (i.e. the JVM considers it worthy of the expensive optimizations).

*Why* the JVM decides one way or another is a much harder question and probably requires in-depth analysis of the JIT code.

Comment: Thanks. Printing the assembly would be a possible way, but I was wondering if there was any exposed API to look into this. Something like a method that is called whenever loop unrolling is done by the JIT, and i can count the number of times it is called as well as the context within which it is called. I looked through the JVMTI and did not find anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no such API, simply because this is **highly** implementation-dependent and only of limited use for *most* applications.

Comment: Thanks. I guess i was expecting too much after playing with JVMTI and Eclipse JDT.

Comment: Actually the whole thing is not only implementation and code specific, one can even influence it with command line options. Goo look at `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see if loop unrolling is being performed in the loop is to specify `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1` as an [argument to the JVM](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) when running your code.

If you have an executable jar, then an example of how you can use this is:

```
java -XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1 -jar your-jar.jar
```

This flag will

> Unroll loop bodies with server compiler intermediate representation node count less than this value

And that'll directly address your question without needing to look at the generated assembly